# onSyncStatusChange is called twice in Dropbox Sync API

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have successfully implemented Dropbox's Sync API into my app. Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SyncStatusListener
{
    private static final String appKey = "xxxxx";
    private static final String appSecret = "xxx";

    private static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;

    private TextView mTestOutput;
    private Button mLinkButton;
    private Button saveButton;
    private EditText txtFile;
    private DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr;

    private static String fileName = "data.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtFile = ( EditText ) findViewById( R.id.writeFile );
        mTestOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_output);
        mLinkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.link_button);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById( R.id.save );

        mLinkButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override 
            public void onClick ( View  view )
            {
                if ( mDbxAcctMgr != null )
                {
                    mDbxAcctMgr.startLink( (Activity)MainActivity.this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX );
                }
            }
        });

        saveButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override 
            public void onClick ( View view )
            {
                SaveFile();   
            }
        });

        mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (mDbxAcctMgr.hasLinkedAccount()) 
        {
            loadFileFromDropbox();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if ( requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX ) 
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
            {
                loadFileFromDropbox();
            } 
            else 
            {
                mTestOutput.setText("Link to Dropbox failed or was cancelled.");
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private void loadFileFromDropbox()
    {
        try
        {
            DbxPath testPath = new DbxPath( DbxPath.ROOT, fileName );

            // Create DbxFileSystem for synchronized file access.
            DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());

            if (dbxFs.isFile(testPath)) 
            {
                String resultData;
                DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open(testPath);

                try 
                {
                    resultData = testFile.readString();
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    testFile.close();
                }
                mTestOutput.append("\nRead file '" + testPath + "' and got data:\n    " + resultData);
                txtFile.setText(resultData);
            } 
            else if (dbxFs.isFolder(testPath)) 
            {
                mTestOutput.append("'" + testPath.toString() + "' is a folder.\n");
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "loadFileFromDropbox Error : " + e.toString() );
        }
    }

    private void SaveFile()
    {
        try
        {
            DbxPath testPath = new DbxPath( DbxPath.ROOT, fileName );
            DbxFileSystem dbxFs = DbxFileSystem.forAccount(mDbxAcctMgr.getLinkedAccount());

            // Create a test file only if it doesn't already exist.
            String fileData = txtFile.getText().toString().trim();

            dbxFs.addSyncStatusListener(this);

            if (!dbxFs.exists(testPath)) 
            {
                DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.create(testPath);
                try 
                {
                    if ( !fileData.equals( "" ) )
                    {
                        testFile.writeString( fileData );
                    }
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    testFile.close();
                }
                mTestOutput.append("\nCreated new file '" + testPath + "'.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                DbxFile testFile = dbxFs.open( testPath );
                try 
                {
                    if ( !fileData.equals( "" ) )
                    {
                        testFile.writeString( fileData );
                    }
                } 
                finally 
                {
                    testFile.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Save Error : " + e.toString() );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSyncStatusChange( DbxFileSystem fs ) 
    {
        try
        {
            if ( fs.getSyncStatus() != null )
            {
                loadFileFromDropbox();
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "OK " + e.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

I have a EditText, which will load the file's content. I can add/update its content and save it on my dropbox account. After saving it calls `onSyncStatusChange()` method more than one time.

Why so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you log the actual status from `onSyncStatusChange`, I imagine it will become clear what's changing each time.

My guess would be that it's called once when the status changes to uploading and then again when the upload is complete. So if you log `fs.getSyncStatus().uploading.inProgress`, you'll see it flip to true and then back to false, which would make sense.

Comment: The log is coming as true, true and then false, false which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Harish Then check the other components of the sync status. I believe you'll always see something changing (even if not the `uploading` field).

Comment: I cant think of any other field that is relevant for me. I'm creating a file and want to know when the file is actually uploaded to  the upload. Its instant when the device is connected but when the device doesn't have any network connectivity, it gets synced when the data connection becomes active. I'm struggling to capture this event, any help?

Comment: I was trying to explain why you might see the same value on consecutive calls. (It probably means another field is changing.) To answer your question, if you start the app and see `uploading.inProgress` as `true`, that means there's a pending upload that's about to happen. Then when you see `false`, you know that upload has completed.